# how to impose a constraints in the NDSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a question about the constraints in Mathematica NDSolve

If I have two linear differential equations

```
NDSolve[x'[t]= A x[t]+B y[t], 
        y'[t]= C x[t]+D y[t], 
        x[0]==0.002, y[0]==0.005, {x,y}, {t,0.10000}]
```

How can I impose the constraint

```
x[t]+y[t] == 1
```

for any time t

Thanks

Comment: For starters, it's not true at `t=0`.

Comment: okay you are right  let x[0]==0.2 and y[0]==0.8 ... how can I keep this wight x[t]+y[t] = 1 for any time t

Comment: After fixing some syntax, you could substitute `{y[t]->1-x[t], y'[t]->-x'[t]}` and solve the resulting equation for `x[t]`.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work

Comment: If `x[t] + y[t] == 1` then `x'[t] == -y'[t]` and you need only one equation. Also, `NDSolve[]` will work only for numerical problems (i.e. no symbolic constants like A, B ...)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that in general you cannot. This is not a limitation of Mathematica, it is a limitation of the mathematics.

You are trying to solve three equations simultaneously:

```
x' = Ax+By
y' = Cx+Dy
1 = x + y
```

I'm going to use lowercase `a,b,c,d` to avoid issues with Mathematica.

You are not required to make a substitution manually, as belisarius suggests. You can simply pick any two of those and ask Mathematica to solve:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; x0 = 0.2; y0 = 0.8;

NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], 
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];
Plot[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[{x[t], y[t]}, %]], {t, 0, 0.01}]

NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], x[t]+y[t]==1, 
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];
Plot[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[{x[t], y[t]}, %]], {t, 0, 0.01}]

NDSolve[{y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], x[t]+y[t]==1,
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];
Plot[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[{x[t], y[t]}, %]], {t, 0, 0.01}]
```

Note that for any of those to work, you will need to specify the constants `a,b,c,d,x0,y0` (and you will need `x0` and `y0` to sum to 1 for the second and third one).

I'm using NDSolve, as you asked, although any of these can also be solved by `DSolve` instead (with or without fixed values of the constants):

```
Clear[a,b,c,d,x0,y0];

DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], 
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]

DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], x[t]+y[t]==1, 
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == 1-x0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]

DSolve[{y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], x[t]+y[t]==1,
 x[0] == x0, y[0] == 1-x0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

However, it is very important to note that with three functional equations and two functions, you can't solve all of them simultaneously. That's why the three graphs produced by `NDSolve` and the three sets of solutions produced by `DSolve` will be different. Note that I have to explicitly force x[0]+y[0]=1 in the latter two cases by giving `1-x0` as an initial value.

Because you have three equations, you either have a system that is inconsistent or overdetermined. If you try to solve all three simultaneously, Mathematica will give an error:

```
NDSolve::overdet:
"There are fewer dependent variables, {x[t],y[t]}, than equations, so the
system is overdetermined."
```

(Similar for `DSolve`.)

My choice of `a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4` makes it inconsistent (hence my three graphs do not agree). You can mess around with `Manipulate` or something to see how they relate, but there are two elementary ways I've got off the top of my head to determine how (if at all) to force the solutions to be consistent for all three equations:

1. Just differentiate `1=x+y`. This gives you `0=x'+y'` which means that you have the restriction `ax+by=cx+dy` throughout, in other words `y=(c-a)/(b-d)x`. This is actually inconsistent with your original constraint `x+y=1`.
2. Consider the linear system of DEs `x'=ax+by` and `y'=cx+dy`. In order for a solution to be a straight line, it must be in the direction of an eigenvector and must pass through the origin. Your constraint `x+y=1` is a line that does not meet those criteria, therefore no solution to the two DEs will satisfy your algebraic equation.

PS I think you have a typo in your original code. You probably want `{t,0,10000}` yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try for example:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == A x[t] + B (1 - x[t]), x[0] == 2/10}, x[t], t]
```

Comment: How does this jive with the alternative `DSolve[{y'[t] == C (1 - y[t]) + D y[t], y[0] == 8/10}, y[t], t]` ?

Comment: @KellenMyers Please see my comment below the question itself

Comment: The comment about `x'=-y'`? That still doesn't jive. You've recommended eliminating one variable, substituting the algebraic equation into one of the differential equations, but the solution you get for `x[t]` will **not** give you a solution for `y[t]` (as `1-x[t]`) that satisfies the second DE.